# Delete few commits in Git branch before merge into master

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

We have three main branches. **develop**, **uat** and **master**. We are in the last week of current sprint. It has been decided to postpone one feature to the next release. That feature is already in **uat** environment. So team wants to keep it in **uat** branch. So before merging into **master**, I have to remove that feature which has 3 commits.

I can create a release branch from **uat**, revert those 3 commits and merge into **master**. But next time conflict might occur in master branch since usual merge **UAT** into **master**. In addition to that, release branch is a temporary branch that will be created for this scenario and it will be deleted after merge.

I don't want to mess up with master branch. Please suggest if there is any better way to handle this scenario.

Comment: With a release branch from uat you can fix any merge conflicts on that release branch before merging it to master again. I think your first thought seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks @Martin the problem is release branch is a temporary branch that will be created for this scenario. It will be gone after current release is completed. We always merge from UAT into master.

Comment: @Ela: that's key information that probably should have been in your original question (you could edit it in now). Note that if you delete the branch name, the commits it retains could be garbage-collected—that seems contrary to the point of a release.

Comment: Thanks @torek Actually we don't have the release branch in our branching strategy. That is a temporary branch and it is like creating a bugfix branch when needed.

Comment: @torek If the branch is merged, you can safely delete the branch name (no history is lost). It is only when the branch is not merged anywhere that those commits would be potentially discarded. [Why Delete Old Git Branches?](https://ardalis.com/why-delete-old-git-branches)

Comment: Another question. Can we skip some features while deploying to production in Continuous delivery process? I believe Production like environment (UAT, staging) is must in CD.

Comment: @crashmstr: As long as it's a real merge (not a squash "merge"), sure. I find that it helps a lot to draw the intended graph, remembering that branch and tag names like "v1.1" point to specific commits (with branch names automatically extending to encompass new commits). It then becomes obvious (or at least not too opaque) what future commits and merges will do.

Comment: I think the simplest practice for this might be to use interactive rebase or equivalently some cherry-picks to sequence the production-ready changes before the not-yet-ready ones, and merge the production-ready ones, leaving the still-pending work right where you want it.

Comment: @Ela Have you delete the commits successfully?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT yes..We have deleted the commits. 2nd scenario helped in our case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow you are using seems: continuous build/deploying for `uat` branch, and then merge `uat` branch into `master` for a new release.

So I will suggest **backup current `uat` branch, remove the three commits on `uat` branch. After merging `uat` branch into `master`, recovery/reapply the three commits on `uat` branch again for next release**.

There have two situations for you to change and recovery/reapply `uat` branch. You can follow one the below situations you meet.

### Situation 1: the three commits are the latest three commits on `uat` branch

Assume the commit history looks as below, and the commit `D`, `E` and `F` are the commits for the feature that you decide to postpone for next release.

```
…---A---B            master
…---C---D---E---F   uat
```

You can use below commands to backup current `uat` branch and then remove the three commits on `uat` branch:

```
git checkout -b temp uat
git checkout uat
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Then the commit history looks like:

```
…---A---B         master
…---C             uat
     \
      D---E---F   temp
```

And now, you can merge `uat` into `master` for the new release, so the commit history will be:

```
…---A---B---G           master
           /
…---------C             uat
           \
            D---E---F   temp
```

Then you can recovery `uat` branch as original by

```
git checkout uat
git merge temp
git branch -D temp
```

Then the commit history looks as below, and the three commits `D`, `E` and `F` will apply for next release when merge `uat` into `master` for next time.

```
…---A---B---G             master
           /
…---------C---D---E---F   uat
```

### Situation 2: the three commits are not the latest commits, there has other commit(s) after the three commits

Assume the commit history as below, and the commits `D`, `E` and `F` are the commits you want to remove. And there have commits `G` and `H` after the three commits.

```
…---A---B    master
…---C---D---E---F---G---H   uat
```

To backup current `uat` and remove the three commits on `uat` branch, you can use below commands:

```
git checkout -b temp uat
git checkout uat
git rebase --onto uat~5 uat~2 uat
```

The commit history will be:

```
…---A---B         master
…---C---G'---H'   uat
         \
          D---E---F---G---H   temp
```

After merge `uat` into `master`, the commit history looks like:

```
…---A---B------I   master
              /
…---C---G'---H'   uat
     \
      D---E---F---G---H   temp
```

Then you can re-apply the three commits `D`, `E` and `F` on `uat` branch by below commands:

```
git checkout temp
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git rebase uat temp
git checkout uat
git merge temp
git branch -D temp
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
…---A---B------I    master
              /
…---C---G'---H'---D'---E'---F'   uat
```

And the three commits `D'`, `E'` and `F'` can be release for next time.